# Convert datatype Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, types

Starting from a Pandas Dataframe with it's setup:

```
B13-111DATA.TIJD    object
dtype: object
                    B13-111DATA.TIJD
StartTime
2020-03-30 00:00:00              292
2020-03-30 00:00:01              292
2020-03-30 00:00:02              292
2020-03-30 00:00:03              292
2020-03-30 00:00:04              292
...                              ...
2020-04-07 23:59:55              333
2020-04-07 23:59:56              333
2020-04-07 23:59:57              333
2020-04-07 23:59:58              333
2020-04-07 23:59:59              333

[777600 rows x 1 columns]
```

This Pandas Dataframe I would like to transform to a structuce like below:

```
B13-111DATA.TIJD    int64 
dtype: object
```

or

```
B13-111DATA.TIJD    float64
dtype: object
```

I tried to use following line:

```
df = df[B13-111DATA.TIJD].astype(float)
```

But it returns me a simple "float" and errors my code

```
print(output.columns.values)
```

with an **error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'".** It looks my dataFrame turned into a series. Could that be the case?

Pretty sure it is something simple many people already encountered here. Any tip or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is there is reaasign DataFrame variable `df` to `Series` (column of DataFrame):

```
df = df['B13-111DATA.TIJD'].astype(float)
```

For correct converting assign back column, so `df` stay `DataFrame`:

```
df['B13-111DATA.TIJD'] = df['B13-111DATA.TIJD'].astype(float)
print (df)
```